# Room get all items with ids from another table

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I have 2 tables, *items* (key = *item_id*) and *details* (key = *details_id*). If *details_id* is present in *details* then *item_id* that is equal to *details_id* will also be present in *items*. I need to get items by all *details_id* from *items* database.

The databases work fine separately but when I try to write query that mentions the 2nd table I get following error:

**error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: details)**

My query:

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM pokemons WHERE item_id IN (SELECT details_id FROM details)")
    fun pagingSourceOffline(): PagingSource<Int, PokemonItemEntity>
```

Comment: If you have  "databases" as opposed to 1 database, then each will be independent of each other. You should very likely have a single database (`@Database` annotated class with the two tables ('@Entity' annotated classes) defined via the entities parameter).

Comment: Declare both tables in the single Database. if you can declare it separately you can use the two database connect and first table output you can insert the second table input...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your tables together you need to declare them in **one** database.

```kotlin
@Database(
    entities = [TableOne::class, TableTwo::class],
    version = 1
)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val tableOneDao: TableOneDao
    abstract val tableTwoDao: TableTwoDao
}
```